# Sort enum array with associate values

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, enums

I have enum like below

```
enum HomeScreenDataType {
    case topBanners([TopBanner])
    case bottomBanner([BottomBanner])
    case productCategory([ProductCategory])
    case favouriteStores([FavouriteStores])
    case subscriber([Subscriber])
}
```

I have an array of that enum
`var homeScreenData = [HomeScreenDataType]()`

5 async API calls will be there for 5 types(TopBanner, BottomBanner, ProductCategory, FavouriteStores, Subscriber) of data and I will append them in above array as I receive data. Once I get data from all 5 APIs, I want to sort them it in specific order(TopBanner, BottomBanner, ProductCategory, FavouriteStores, Subscriber), how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This would work if the enum could have a raw value that can be used for sorting but that isn't possible in this case but we could fake one by creating a computed property

```
var sortValue: Int {
    switch self {
    case .topBanners(_):
        return 1
    case .bottomBanner(_):
        return 2
    case .productCategory(_):
        return 3
    case .favouriteStores(_):
        return 4
    case .subscriber(_):
        return 5
    }
}
```

and then use it when sorting

```
homeScreenData.sort(by: { $0.sortValue < $1.sortValue })
```

or make the enum conform to `Comparable`

```
extension HomeScreenDataType: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: HomeScreenDataType, rhs: HomeScreenDataType) -> Bool {
        lhs.sortValue < rhs.sortValue
    }
}
```

to simplify the sort call

```
homeScreenData.sort()
```